# check IP in session

Tags: php, session

every time user login to my website I put his userID and userIP in session, and check, in every page, if session userID exist, and if userIP equal to his IP.

So If user change the ID value in the session than the IP won't be equal to his IP

```
if ($_SESSION['userIP'] != getenv("REMOTE_ADDR") )
```

My question is why. I don't remmeber why changing the userID value (inside the session) will make the userIP not being equal to his real IP ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show your code please. (the session setting code)

Comment: dido. Why aren't you using $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];? What code is used to set the session? Is evn set up right? It's not always enabled but superglobals are.

Comment: What you're doing makes no sense to me.